# Demodulaion of AM (modulate signal is square wave)

Tags: demodulation

[image]
MY modulate signal is square wave. When I used the diode detector technique to demodulate AM signal I get a distortion.
what technique  is used to demodulate the AM square wave ?

Comment: You may need to adjust (reduce) the load resistor (across the capacitor) to reduce distortion on the demodulated waveform.

Answer (score 1):

The same technique is used, but you need to know that the bandwidth of your receiver (and of the transmitter) will put limitations on your square wave.  A pure square wave requires infinite bandwidth.  Getting reasonably close requires a wide bandwidth.   So you will probably need to accept a less-then ideal result.

Also, the action of that capacitor will remove the highest frequencies, also distorting a square wave.  You can make the value smaller, but at some point, the carrier signal will start to reappear.

Comment: Yet another way is to code squarewave transitions with AM bursts.